# Rendering across tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap in my rails app and in particular, I would like to extend Bootstrap's tabbable functionality in the following sense:
 
Each user of my site can have multiple profiles, namely model User has_many profiles, and I would like to display these profiles across tabs in their user/show page. Each profile has a name attribute which I want to display on the tab itself. 
I was previously rendering these profiles using the typical conventions:

On user/show page:

```
<%= render 'shared/prof %>
```

shared/_prof:

```
<% if @prof_items.any? %>
  <ol class="profiles">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/prof_item', collection: @prof_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @prof_items %>
<% end %>
```

shared/_prof_items

```
<li id="<%= prof_item.id %>">
...content...
</li>
```

users_controller:

```
...
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @profiles = @user.profiles.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @profile = @user.profiles.build
  @prof_items = @user.prof.paginate(page: params[:page])
  ...
end
...
```

So essentially I would like the outputted html to be like this:

```
<div class="tabbable" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabHeaders">
  <li class="active">
   <a href="#tab_<%=prof_item.id%>" data-toggle="tab">Name of first profile</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#tab_<%=prof_item.id%>" data-toggle="tab">Name of second profile</a>
  </li>
  #and so on for each prof_item
 </ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
 <div class="tab-pane active id="<%=prof_item.id%>">
  #render first profile item
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane" id="<%=prof_item.id%>">
  #render second profile item
 </div>
</div>
```

However I'm not sure what code I need in user/show.html.erb, what code I need in shared/_prof_item.html.erb, and what code I need in shared/_prof.html.erb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using rails facility to render collections:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/prof_item', collection: @prof_items) %>
<%= render partial: 'shared/profile', collection: @profiles) %>
```

shared/_profile.html.erb: # use local variable profile

```
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="<%=profile.id%>">
     #render first profile
     </div>
```

shared/_prof_item.html.erb # use local variable prof_item

```
    <li>
    <a href="#tab_<%=prof_item.id%>" data-toggle="tab">Name of second profile item</a>
    </li>
```